# Interval needing transition from css

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition

I know jquery can do it but I heard that css is faster because it doesn't have all the logic involved in javascript or jquery. So here is the issue, the fade is working but its happening too fast between text switches. I've tried multiple variants but just can't figure it out.

```
window.onload = function() {
   runSkills();
}

runSkills = function() {
    var array = [
        "W.",
        "G",
        "P",  
        "C",
        "A",
        "J"
];

var i = -1;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    i++;
    var dyText = $(".dynamicText:last");
    dyText.addClass('dynamicTextOff');
    dyText.text(array[i]);
    if(i == array.length)
        i = 0;
}, 2000);
}
```

CSS:

```
.dynamicText {
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 550ms ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 550ms ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 550ms ease;
    transition: opacity 550ms ease;
}

.dynamicTextOff {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="centeredIntro"> 
    <div class="introMessage">
            Let Gravity do the Work
        </div>
        <span class="staticText">Hi, my name is <span class="title">Carine.</span>
        I'm a <span class="title dynamicText"></span>
        </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you actually want to achieve?  Showing us your code and saying it's not working doesn't help us help you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
functionvar i = -1;
function changetext()
{
    i++;
    var dyText = $(".dynamicText:last");
    dyText.addClass('dynamicTextOff');
    dyText.text(array[i]);
    if(i == array.length)
        i = 0;
    setTimeout(changetext,2000);

}
```

Hope it helped :)

UPDATE

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var i=-1;
    var array=["W.","G","P","C","A","J"];
    var dyText;
    function changetext()
    {
      i++;
      dyText=$(".dynamicText:last").addClass("dynamicTextOff").text(array[i]);
      if(i==array.length)
      {
        i=0;
      }
      setTimeout(changetext,2000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I only see it flashing once though

Comment: Sorry, I wrote functionvar, it should be only var

Comment: But it still would only flash once...i hate giving up but I'm thinkgin I probably either need to do animation or just do jquery fadein, delay, fade out......I just felt like I should know how to do it with just css

Comment: I didn't get to try this yet because I just got on here to say I found a solution...although I am not really sure if its performance is any worse because of it...but essentially i added a second interval to toggle the classes and it lasts half as long as the interval that switches the text.

Comment: not sure if you knew this but the dynamicTExtOff has opacity set to 0 so I'm not sure how it gets "turned back on" so to speak

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/d741xa09/1/

```
runSkills = function() {
    var array = [
        "W.",
        "G",
        "P",  
        "C",
        "A",
        "J"
    ];

    var i = -1;
    var dyText = $(".dynamicText");


    dyText.addClass('dynamicTextOff');

    setInterval(function() {
        i += 1;
        dyText.text(array[i]);
        dyText.removeClass('dynamicTextOff');

        setTimeout(function() {
            dyText.addClass('dynamicTextOff');
        }, 500);



        if(i == array.length) {
            i = -1;
        }
    }, 2000);

}    


runSkills();
```

Comment: Yes that's it. I ended up accomplishing the same thing with two set intervals but I'm curious to look into what the set timeout does. I wonder if there's a way to make the text last longer before switching off

Comment: setTimeout only calls once. setInterval will call indefinitely until you cancel it. To make the text last longer change the value in the setTimeout to 1500 or something less than 2000 (value in the setInterval).